# SQL Server 2014 Select Records not present in other table with Max function

Tags: sql-server, select

I have 2 tables, Customers and Sales

I need to extract from Sales all Customers that have not yet been loaded into Customers table and I built the following query that was working quite well before I've been asked to add the 2 `MAX()` fields.

Here is the query:

```
    INSERT INTO Customers (.....)
    SELECT distinct 
        d.UserName, 
        d.postalCode, 
        d.location, 
        d.country,  
        max(d.invoiceamount) invoiceamount, 
        max(d.itemscount) itemscount,
        d.storeID
    FROM S.dbo.[Sales] d
    LEFT JOIN G.dbo.Customers s ON d.Username=s.UserName
    WHERE s.UserName IS NULL
    AND d.username IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY d.UserName, d.postalCode, d.location,    
    d.country, max(d.invoiceamount), max(d.itemscount), d.storeID
```

but the query does not accept max() in grouping:

In another situation I used `CROSS APPLY` but since here I have to extract records where Username is NULL in one table... I do not know how to build the query.

can you please give some hints?

Comment: Try removing the `MAX` functions and their columns in the `GROUP BY` clause: `GROUP BY d.UserName, d.postalCode, d.location,    
    d.country,  d.storeID`

Comment: Yes Felix, you're fully right, was too tired tonight.. in fact I merged 2 different mail and posted the wrong question: real issue is quite different. perhaps is better if I make another question.. your answer is fully right if referred to original question. Sorry again

Comment: Please don't change your question entirely after you ask it. If you solve the original question and want to ask a new one, then you should (1) accept an answer, if an answer helped you solve the problem, and (2) ask a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `max()` in the `group by`:

```
INSERT INTO Customers (.....)
    SELECT d.UserName, d.postalCode, d.location, d.country,  
           max(d.invoiceamount) invoiceamount, 
           max(d.itemscount) itemscount,
           d.storeID
    FROM S.dbo.[Sales] d LEFT JOIN
         G.dbo.Customers s
         ON d.Username = s.UserName
    WHERE s.UserName IS NULL AND d.username IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY d.UserName, d.postalCode, d.location, d.country, d.storeID;
```

All the non-aggregated columns should be in the `group by`.

Comment: Yes Gordon, you're fully right, was too tired tonight.. in fact I merged 2 different mail and posted the wrong question: real issue is quite different.
perhaps is better if I make another question.. your answer is fully right if referred to original question. Sorry again.